# Text on WebView takes up a third of the screen

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I have a text that I load into a WebView. There is a table in a text. Without table text takes up whole sreen's width. With table text looks like this:

[image]

how can I make the text with table fit the width of the screen?
here is my webView's initializing:

```
    webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
    webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
    webView.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
    webView.settings.displayZoomControls = false
    webView.setInitialScale(1)
    webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
    webView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT
    webView.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
    webView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)
    webView.settings.setAppCachePath(cacheDir.absolutePath)
    webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
    webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    webView.loadUrl(link)
```

Comment: Does it fit if you use a regular browser?

Comment: can you paste the  content of the link ? probably the formatting in the html

Comment: Have you tried changing different scale and zoom levels?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change this behaviour from the webview. Try to use some responsive framework in your html.